# How to write on images using EmguCV in C#

Tags: c#, image, emgucv, image-text

I wanna write on images using **EmguCV** in **Windows Form C#** In actual I wanna create a simple app for images as an image editor. Its simple purpose is to open images through an open file dialogue I can open the file but now I can't get any help or resource on **How to write on images?**. Let me explain my question through some image examples:

**Image Before Editing:**

[image]

**Image after Editing:**

[image]

So how can I do this using **EmguCV** in **C#**
I am newbie in dealing with images if there any way so kindly tell me.
And If there is not a such function involved in writing on images using **EmguCV** then please tell the alternative if any of you know??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write on images with `CvInvoke.PutText`, one simple example is here:

```
// load the image        
Mat image = new Mat("test.png");
// write "hello!" in red(0,0,255) at 100,100 coordinate from the top left corner
CvInvoke.PutText(image, "hello!", new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100), FontFace.HersheySimplex, 1.0, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
// display the result
CvInvoke.Imshow("Image with text", image);
// wait for user input to dismiss the image
CvInvoke.WaitKey();
// free allocated memory
image.Dispose();
```

Seems confusing for somebody new to EmguCV but it really is just a matter of looking at what each parameters do, more info in the [EmguCV official documentation.](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.0/document/html/37ada42e-a5c3-caa1-dfa7-a4a64251a059.htm)